# Master branch is empty at remote Github

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a local github repo and I pushed repository to remote with below command:

```
git push origin --all
```

Now on remote All branches available with respective code but master branch is empty. So please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Note: I have installed git lfs then pushed code with above command.

Comment: What dies 'git Remote Show Origin' say?

Comment: What was the output of your push command?

Comment: I dont know why master is not pushed but when i force pushed then master is reflected at origin. git push -f origin --all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does Your local master look like? Maybe there is some policy of pushing/merging into master on origin.

Comment: What server are You using?